# Why is the Chrome inspector showing different sizes for same-sized elements in an SVG?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, web-inspector, html-rendering

In the following snippet, the Chrome inspector reports that the `div` and `foreignObject` are 50% larger than the `rect` and text node, even though they all take up the same space on screen. Firefox reports the same sizes for all four. What's causing Chrome to report a difference?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">
 <rect fill="#f5f5a0" width="244" height="73"></rect>
 <foreignObject width="244" height="73">
  <div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus efficitur quam sapien, in varius ipsum mollis quis.
  </div>
 </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Chrome inspector results:

[image: Chrome inspector screenshots showing text node is 244x73, div is 366x108, foreignobject is 366x109.5, and rect is 244x73]

Firefox inspector results:

[image: Firefox inspector screenshots showing text node is 242x73, div is 244x75, foreignObject is 244x73, and rect is 244x73]

Comment: Can't repro in Chrome 80 and 84 on macOS. But anyway, the answer to  "What's causing Chrome to report a difference?" is simply "a bug". Report this to [the ones who can fix it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks! I think I found an existing report for this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by a known bug in Chrome: [Issue 738022: getBoundingClientRect reports double size for foreignObject children on a HiDPI monitor](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=738022).

The reported size is scaled by `devicePixelRatio`, which on my machine is `1.5`.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed a bug in chrome.

Here's my foreignObject size on windows 10 chrome 80.0.3987.149 (devicePixelRatio: 2).

[windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfc7R.png)

Mac chrome works well (devicePixelRatio: 2):
[mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXkSs.png)